# What is the "->" in code?

Tags: php

I am trying to learn how a specific project works and while I can find most functions online, I found one that stumps me.
I see "->" appear every so often in the code, but have no idea what it does.
What does "->" mean in PHP or Joomla?

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Comment: http://us1.php.net/manual/en/classobj.examples.php Manual works well. Its the operator that 'points to' an objects methods and parameters. IE a Class object has a parameter named $count. You access that parameter by pointing to it. Class->count

Comment: Joomla is a system built on PHP, it's not a language by itself. Joomla can't do anything that the underlying PHP it's built in couldn't do already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the object operator in PHP. It is used to access child properties and methods of classes. Its Javascript and Java equivalent is the `.` operator. It would be used in PHP like this

```
class foo{
    public $bar="qux";
    public function display(){
        echo $this->bar;
    }

}
$myFoo=new foo();
$myFoo->display(); //displays "qux"
```

Comment: Note: should be `$myFoo->display()`

Comment: @DamienPirsy thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 0):

Its like the . operator in C++ and Java.  Refers to members within a class.   C++ also uses the -> to access members when the variable preceding the -> is a pointer to a class rather than an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0):

-> is the way used to call a method.

In C, C++, C#, Java you use . (dot) notation to call a method:

```
operation.sum(a, b);
```

In php you do it using ->

```
operation->sum(a,b)
```

Comment: It doesn't necessarily call a method

Comment: you use -> in C++ too when the variable preceding it is a pointer rather than instance